# AngularJs/GitHub : How do i clone angular-seed to my new project without any history?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git, github, angular-seed

I have followed the steps from the below documentation from angular-seed github page and created a new project and pushed my project to github as `https://github.com/selvaonline/StickyTodos` , but still i am seeing the history of old remote angular-seed's history and contributors. I have done unshallow my old cloned repo but still i am getting the old history.

> From Angular-Seed Documentation which i followed... If you just want
>   to start a new project without the angular-seed commit history then
>   you can do:
>
> git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/angular/angular-seed.git
>    The depth=1 tells git to only pull down one commit
>   worth of historical data.

Steps which involved to create the github project

**Step 1: Clone the angular-seed to my local repo**

```
C:\Projects\StickyTodos>git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/angular/angular-seed.git
```

I have created the ssh key and added to my github account. then i have followed the below steps.

```
Selva@SelvaOnline MINGW64 ~/.ssh
$ ssh-add git_rsa
Identity added: git_rsa (git_rsa)

Selva@SelvaOnline MINGW64 ~/.ssh
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.XX.XXX.XXX' to the list of known hosts.
Hi selvaonline/StickyTodos! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Selva@SelvaOnline MINGW64 /c/projects/StickyTodos (master)
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/selvaonline/StickyTodos.git



Selva@SelvaOnline MINGW64 /c/projects/StickyTodos (master)
$ git remote add old https://github.com/angular/angular-seed.git

Selva@SelvaOnline MINGW64 /c/projects/StickyTodos (master)
$ git fetch --unshallow old
remote: Counting objects: 2555, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (983/983), done.
remote: Total 25Receiving objects55 (de: lt 99% (a 14254129), reused 25/229 (555), delta 111.7403), 7 paMiB ck| 340.00-reu Ksed iB0[K
Receiving objects: 100% (2555/2555), 11.91 MiB | 340.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1429/1429), completed with 14 local objects.
From https://github.com/angular/angular-seed
 * [new branch]      master     -> old/master
 * [new branch]      move-bower -> old/move-bower
 * [new branch]      v0.10.x    -> old/v0.10.x


$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/selvaonline/StickyTodos.git


Selva@SelvaOnline MINGW64 /c/projects/StickyTodos (master)
$ git add .

Selva@SelvaOnline MINGW64 /c/projects/StickyTodos (master)
$ git commit -m "First Commit"
[master a4667c4] First Commit
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
 delete mode 160000 angular-seed

Selva@SelvaOnline MINGW64 /c/projects/StickyTodos (master)
$ git push origin
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has changed in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the traditional behavior, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

Since Git 2.0, Git defaults to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Counting objects: 2590, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (994/994), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2590/2590), 11.92 MiB | 606.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2590 (delta 1438), reused 2558 (delta 1424)
To https://github.com/selvaonline/StickyTodos.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

So i have my angular-seed cloned local repo and it has been pushed to github remote repo. What is the best solution you can give me to remove the angular-seed's history from my project?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with angular syntax on angular-seed github documentation page.

git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/angular/angular-seed.git (as per documentation)

git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/angular/angular-seed.git (correct syntax)

Thanks @Jeff Auriemma (http://jdauriemma.com/)